# How to align columns of two separate matrices?

Tags: math-mode, equations, align, matrices

I have two equations involving matrices in an align environment. One of the matrices is wider than the other. How do I align them so that they are equally wide?

A minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
    g^\mathrm{x} &:= \frac{1}{8}\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 & 1 \\ -2 & 0 & 2 \\
       -1 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\\
    g^\mathrm{y} &:= \frac{1}{8}\begin{bmatrix} -1 & -2 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\
       1 & 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

This produces

[image]

Comment: Although I've accepted Arun Debray's answer as it works here, is there a more general method that does not involve adding phantom entries so as not having to actually modify larger matrices.

Comment: all matrices or arrays that i'm familiar with require that the desired longest entry in each column be present in at least one row.  so no, the best you can do (to my knowledge) is put phantoms in one row (the first is the easiest) for any column which has only narrow entries.  so the answer provided is a good one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach is to right-align both matrices, using `\begin{bmatrix*}[r]`…`\end{bmatrix*}` (from the `mathtools` package) instead of `bmatrix`. Then, adding `\phantom{-}0` to entries in the second and third columns of the first matrix will add the correct amount of space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align} %                                      ↓ Here
    g^\mathrm{x} &:= \frac{1}{8}\begin{bmatrix*}[r] -1 & \phantom{-}0 &
    \phantom{-}1 \\ -2 & 0 & 2 \\ -1 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix*}\\
    g^\mathrm{y} &:= \frac{1}{8}\begin{bmatrix*}[r] -1 & -2 & -1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix*}
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The package `nicematrix` has tools designed to address that kind of problem. It provides an environment `{NiceMatrixBlock}` with a key `auto-columns-width` to ensure the same width for all the columns of the environments `{bNiceMatrix}` present within the scope of the environment `{NiceMatrixBlock}`. The environment `{bNiceMatrix}`, provided by `nicematrix` is similar to the classical `{bmatrix}` of `amsmath` but with new functionalities.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceMatrixBlock}[auto-columns-width]
\begin{align}
g^{\mathrm{x}} &
:= \frac{1}{8}\begin{bNiceMatrix} -1 & 0 & 1 \\ -2 & 0 & 2 \\ -1 & 0 & 1 \end{bNiceMatrix} \\
g^{\mathrm{y}} &
:= \frac{1}{8}\begin{bNiceMatrix} -1 & -2 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 2 & 1 \end{bNiceMatrix}
\end{align}
\end{NiceMatrixBlock}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations.

[image: Output of the above code]